# Failed to connect to queue manager runtime exception in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, exception, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am using Eclipse and i-series Navigator for database. When I run my application it is showing:

```
Exception=Exception001{Id=0,Message=java.lang.RuntimeException:
     Failed to connect to queue manager,Severity=2}],
     ServiceID=GetCustomerProfile2,Status=2,TransactionID=1}
```

What causes it and how do I fix it?

Comment: Truth be told I have no idea, but this link might be usefull:
http://www.eclipse.org/newsgroups/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your specific problem is but first port of call for all IBM product problems is the `publib` documentation site (iSeries stuff [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzahg/icmain.htm)) or the "Navigator for i" support site [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/navigator/index.html).

The first thing I would do is to contact your iSeries support people and find out if there's a problem on their boxes with MQ. If they say no, then you need to figure out where iSeries Navigator is storing its logs on your local machine (since it's more likely to be a problem there).

The iSeries boxes are like nothing you've ever seen before (even the guys that work with System z think they're a bit strange :-). Better to get help from someone that knows about them.

Comment: The boxes are not strange but unique ;-) Notice that MQ on the iSeries from the user point of view is normal MQ. Managing the stuff on the iSeries itself is a little bit different, but you can also do it from the Eclipse component. At least, connecting to MQ on the iSeries is 100% identical to connecting to another machine.